# What is the volume of the shape formed by rotating a square-minus-a-quarter-circle about one of the sides of the square?

Tags: geometry, volume, rotations

We have a quarter circle in a square.

[image]

Please calculate the volume after rotating the colored part around $BC$ for $360^\circ$. I prefer solutions without calculus but if you could'nt find one without it, mentioning the calculus way is also really helpful.

PS: Don't pay attention to the thing near the AB and AD sides. It means the square side is equal to 3 but it does not matter. You can imagine any size.

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? An actual formula in ٣ ? What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? The area that are rotating is the "area of the square minus the area of quarter circle". After rotation, you get a cylinder with half of the sphere cut out of it (or two quarters cut out of it depending on which edge you use as axis of rotation).

Comment: [Pappus's (Second) Centroid Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) says that, for a region rotated about an external axis, $$\text{volume}=\text{area}\times\text{(distance traveled by centroid)}$$ While the exact location of the shaded region's centroid may not be obvious, what *is* obvious is that the centroid is closer to $BC$ than to $AD$; so, rotating about the different sides gives different volumes. ... Anyway, please say more about the kind of help you want. Are you looking to *derive* the volume using calculus? Or just to calculate it using known formulas?

Comment: Rotate "through" or "around"?

Comment: I mean around. Thanks for mentioning that. I should have fixed that sooner!

Comment: Still interested in solution?

Comment: Actually not anymore.  I learned how to use integral to solve such problems, but if you have better ideas please share.